# Every finite group is finitely presented, but how to do this effectively?

Tags: group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Aluffi II.8.3 suggests proving that every finite group can be finitely presented.

Clearly, we could just present a group via its whole underlying set as the set over which we construct the free group, and $\{ g_i g_j = g_k | \forall g_i, g_j \in G \}$ as the relations, so the proof is easy.

But the question I have is slightly different: is it possible to do this more effectively (with less relations listed explicitly) for an arbitrary group? For instance, $S_3$ is represented as $(\{ x, y \} \mid x^2, y^3, xyxy)$ earlier in the book, which lists far less relations than the whole multiplication table for $S_3$.

Comment: Why should you expect to be able to answer this generally for arbitrary groups?

Comment: At the very least, you should make it a bit clearer what you mean by "more effectively".

Comment: @DonThousand it feels like there's a lot of redundancy in listing the whole table. Cancellation implies lot of things, stating the order for all elements of finite order is sufficient, and so on.

Comment: You may be interested in the [word problem for groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups).

Comment: One can prove that for a group of order $n$, any minimal generating set has size $\leq \log_2(n)$. So you can do things way more efficiently than $n$ generators and $n^2$ relations (of course if you have a generating set with $r$ elements you need at most $r^2$ relations, and very often you will need less). This is as efficient as it gets, at least asymptotically,  for generators since the groups $(\mathbb{Z/2Z})^n$ *need* $n$ generators. I think there is a formula for the number of generators of a subgroup of a free group in terms of the index, but I can't remember

Comment: This is actually a very important and difficult question, and finding good presentations for various classes of finite groups is still a hot research topic. It is particularly important to find such presentations for the finite simple groups. For example, it is now known that all finite simple groups $G$, with the possible exception of the Ree groups $^2G_2(3^{2k+1})$, have presentations of size $O(\log |G|)$.

Comment: @Max Your claim that if you have a generating set with $r$ elements then you need at most $r^2$ relations is not true in general. For example $A_5^3$ can be generated with $2$ generators, but would need at least $5$ (and possibly more) relations.

Comment: @DerekHolt : you're right, I wrote too quickly. the claim about the minimal number of generators is true however

Comment: @Derek what do you mean by "size" of a presentation? Just #gen+#rel, or something more subtle (e.g. taking into account lengths of relators)?

Comment: @user1729 I meant size in the Computer Science sense of bit length, but that's essentially equivalent to #gens + #rels + total length of relators. There are some issues here: a word written as $x^n$ has size $O(\log n)$ but word length $n$. But you can resolve this by introducing $O(\log n)$ new generators and reducing the total relator length to $O(\log n)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen%E2%80%93Schreier_theorem) which goes by the names "the Schreier index formula" and "the Nielsen–Schreier formula". Interpreted for this question, it says that a generating set of size $n$ for $G$ requires at most $1+|G|(n-1)$ relators. This gives a reasonable upper-bound for the size of a presentation (where size=#gen+#rel). If $n$ is the minimum possible size of a generating set then:
$$\min(\text{size of presentation})\leq|G|(n-1)+n+1$$
According to the comments to the question, $n\leq\log_2(|G|)$ so we get:
$$\min(\text{size of presentation})\leq|G|(\log_2(|G|)-1)+\log_2(|G|)+1$$
For example, if $G$ is a non-abelian finite simple group then $G$ can be generated by $2$ elements (this is a theorem). Hence, $G$ has a presentation of size $|G|+3$, which is pretty neat!

We can usually do better because this formula is about generation of a subgroup of a free group, while we want *normal* generation of the same subgroup.

Comment: You could ask whether every finite group has a presentation with at most $r$ generators and at most (say) $r^2$ relations, where $r = \log_2 |G|$ (note that for $G$ elementary abelian of order $2^r$ we need $r$ generators and $r(r+1)/2$ relations). Since you can combine presentations for group extensions, I believe that this can be proved for groups that do not have $^2G_2(q)$ as composition factors. $^2G_2(q)$ has order about $q^7$, and the smallest known presentations have $O(q)$ relations.

Comment: @Derek Out of interest, do you consider this to be a worthwhile research topic? (Your wording of "You could ask" sounded like a suggestion! I don't have a feel for what's research-worthy in finite groups, but I would be surprised if no one had thought about this problem before. It seems easier than the definition of "size" you mentioned above.)

Comment: The problem with this as a research topic is that there is an apparently very difficult open problem remaining, which is whether there exist small (i.e. size $O(\log |G|)$) presentations of the Ree groups $^2G_2(3^{2k+1})$. Another open problem in the area is whether all finite $p$-groups have an *efficient* presentation (which is defined in terms of generator and relation numbers and the rank of the Schur Multiplier), and there might be scope for incremental results there.